# Pandas inconsistent in separating csv file

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, csv

I am trying to read a csv file into a pandas dataframe.

When I read the file into a dataframe using the pandas.read_csv() function it separates the data properly in some rows, but not all. I have looked everywhere but cannot find an answer. The file is 80 MB my guess wouldn't be on the size of the file.

The line of code that I use is :
 `df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=";")`

Below are a snip from the first few rows of the actual CSV and the resulting dataframe.
[snip from the actual csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5RSp.png)

[snip from the resulting dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCBuM.png)

I have used the pandas read csv plenty and never experienced this issue other than when I had indicated the wrong separator.

Initially the csv file was comma separated but as it also contains decimal values so I changed the commas to semi-colons.
I tried various separators nothing works, I also tried using the delimiter instead of sep but to no avail. Nothing seems to work

Comment: Please add a data sample of your csv to the question, so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: screenshots should be avoided.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to upload a sample of the data to stackoverflow.
I did manage to resolve the issue by performing the data separation in excel